# Error converting bytecode to dex: Exception parsing classes while Enabling Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I am using a library module imported as .AAR in my project and everything works fine untill i enable proguard. After enabling Proguard the library  gives the following Exception on building the project.

**I tried everything from Cleaning,Building, Rebuilding the project.
Also tried modifying gradle version from 2.3.0 to 3.3.0 but all in vain.**

I have to kept Obfuscation on(which i am not able to do till now).

Tried adding all these to my `proguard.txt` file:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
#-dontobfuscate
# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
#-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

Exception:

> {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing
>   classes","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL
>   EXCEPTION:\njava.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing
>   classes\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)\nCaused by:
>   com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name
>   (**hk/com/domainname/libname/r**) does not match path
>   (**hk/com/domainname/libname/R.class**)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)\n\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)\n\t...
>   21 more\n","tool":"Dex"}

Comment: You might have this issue --> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html -- if not then add your gradle file in your question for people to check

Comment: Multidexing has already been handled in the app, Not related to it.

Comment: Then try Cleaing the Project  followed by Make Project instead of Rebuilding it  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJK7J.png

Comment: Make and clean is executed fine but while running the build on selected device, Build fails with this error

Comment: @AmritpalSingh Can you post your build.gradle here?